# W/System.err: at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that communicate with a RESTful web service I wrote. Using Volley for GET methods ho name of a table is awesome and easy, but I can't put my finger on the get methods he don't have name of table

how i can take field from a response of my post request this is my response

```
enter code here

 [
 {
    "fullname": "IDRISS SAMI",
    "accountnumber": "0825005896788",
    "rib": "10403082500589678844",
    "iban": "",
    "name": "COMPTE SPECIAL EPARGNE",
    "balance": "1462,6580"
},
{
    "fullname": "IDRISS SAMI",
    "accountnumber": "0821006348788",
    "rib": "10403082100634878827",
    "iban": "",
    "name": "COMPTE CHEQUE",
    "balance": "6105,5590"
}
```

]
this is my code

```
enter code here
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String firstName = response.getString("fullname");
                            int age = employee.getInt("accountnumber");
                            String mail = employee.getString("name");
                             Toast.makeText(ActivityUserProfile.this, "ok"+firstName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            mTextViewResult.append(firstName + ", " + String.valueOf(age) + ", " + mail + "\n\n");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mQueue.add(reques);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting a JSONArray as a response in which case you need to use a JSONArrayRequest.

```
 JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                 //this method returns the json array
                }
            },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               //this method is called if any error in fetching jsonArray
                }
            });
```

Comment: this is the same method i want to see the response

Comment: No, it's not the same method as yours. I am using a JsonArrayRequest while you're using a JsonObjectRequest

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem @Ouertani Saiid ?